# single word for intense/deep/thorough of technical discussion

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Please suggest a single word for intense,deep,thorough,prolonged technical discussions

Comment: got to say 'lectures'

Comment: It's usually not *tweet*, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider ***[brainstorm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brainstorm)*** which may apply also  to technical discussions:

> - To think of or produce (a solution to a problem, for example) by brainstorming.

(AHD)

Comment: Thank you Josh. I also found words like thorough, comprehensive, in-depth. But brainstorming looks more suitable. Thanks again